# Issue with Cursor in Database

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I am having a problem trying to get the user details after signing in. I dont know if the     problem is from the Database itself or a problem with using the Cursor.

**Here is the** ***CODE***

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Log.d("SQLite OnCreate", "Creating table");
    String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGIN + "("

    + KEY_NAME + " VARCHAR (255), " + KEY_MAIL + " VARCHAR (255), "
            + KEY_PASSWORD + " VARCHAR (255), " + KEY_ID
            + " VARCHAR(255), " + "unique_id " + "VARCHAR (255), "
            + KEY_COURSE1 + " VARCHAR(255), " + KEY_COURSE2
            + " VARCHAR(255), " + KEY_COURSE3 + " VARCHAR(255), "
            + KEY_COURSE4 + " VARCHAR(255), " + KEY_COURSE5
            + " VARCHAR(255), " + KEY_COURSE6 + " VARCHAR(255) " +     ");";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
    Log.d("SQLite OnCreate", "table created");

}

public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {
    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // Move to first row
    cursor.moveToNext();
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
        user.put("password", cursor.getString(3));
        user.put("email", cursor.getString(2));
        user.put("regId", cursor.getString(4));
        user.put("unique_id", cursor.getString(5));
        user.put("course1", cursor.getString(6));
        user.put("course2", cursor.getString(7));
        user.put("course3", cursor.getString(8));
        user.put("course4", cursor.getString(9));
        user.put("course5", cursor.getString(10));
        user.put("course6", cursor.getString(11));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    // return user
    return user;
}
```

And in the Activity:

```
DatabaseStudents dbo = new DatabaseStudents(getApplicationContext());
            HashMap<String, String> details = dbo.getUserDetails();
             course1 = Integer.parseInt(details.get("course1"));
             course2 = Integer.parseInt(details.get("course2"));
             course3 = Integer.parseInt(details.get("course3"));
             course4 = Integer.parseInt(details.get("course4"));
             course5 = Integer.parseInt(details.get("course5"));
             course6 = Integer.parseInt(details.get("course6"));
```

BUT the logcat shows an error saying:

```
11-23 22:49:28.051: E/AndroidRuntime(2059): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-23 22:49:28.051: E/AndroidRuntime(2059): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start      activity ComponentInfo{guc.edu.iremote/guc.edu.iremote.Main}:     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 11 from CursorWindow.  Make sure     the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
11-23 22:49:28.051: E/AndroidRuntime(2059):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
11-23 22:49:28.051: E/AndroidRuntime(2059):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
11-23 22:49:28.051: E/AndroidRuntime(2059):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
11-23 22:49:28.051: E/AndroidRuntime(2059):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
11-23 22:49:28.051: E/AndroidRuntime(2059):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-23 22:49:28.051: E/AndroidRuntime(2059):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-23 22:49:28.051: E/AndroidRuntime(2059):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-23 22:49:28.051: E/AndroidRuntime(2059):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-23 22:49:28.051: E/AndroidRuntime(2059):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-23 22:49:28.051: E/AndroidRuntime(2059):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-23 22:49:28.051: E/AndroidRuntime(2059):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-23 22:49:28.051: E/AndroidRuntime(2059):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-23 22:49:28.051: E/AndroidRuntime(2059): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:     Couldn't read row 0, col 11 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized     correctly before accessing data from it.
11-23 22:49:28.051: E/AndroidRuntime(2059):     at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
11-23 22:49:28.051: E/AndroidRuntime(2059):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:434)
11-23 22:49:28.051: E/AndroidRuntime(2059):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
11-23 22:49:28.051: E/AndroidRuntime(2059):     at guc.edu.iremote.DatabaseStudents.getUserDetails(DatabaseStudents.java:117)
11-23 22:49:28.051: E/AndroidRuntime(2059):     at guc.edu.iremote.Main.onCreate(Main.java:87)
11-23 22:49:28.051: E/AndroidRuntime(2059):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
11-23 22:49:28.051: E/AndroidRuntime(2059):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
11-23 22:49:28.051: E/AndroidRuntime(2059):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
11-23 22:49:28.051: E/AndroidRuntime(2059):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
 cursor.moveToNext();
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
        user.put("password", cursor.getString(3));
        user.put("email", cursor.getString(2));
        user.put("regId", cursor.getString(4));
        user.put("unique_id", cursor.getString(5));
        user.put("course1", cursor.getString(6));
        user.put("course2", cursor.getString(7));
        user.put("course3", cursor.getString(8));
        user.put("course4", cursor.getString(9));
        user.put("course5", cursor.getString(10));
        user.put("course6", cursor.getString(11));
    }
```

To this:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
            user.put("password", cursor.getString(3));
            user.put("email", cursor.getString(2));
            user.put("regId", cursor.getString(4));
            user.put("unique_id", cursor.getString(5));
            user.put("course1", cursor.getString(6));
            user.put("course2", cursor.getString(7));
            user.put("course3", cursor.getString(8));
            user.put("course4", cursor.getString(9));
            user.put("course5", cursor.getString(10));
            user.put("course6", cursor.getString(11));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

`cursor.moveToFirst()` moves the cursor to the first row and returns false if the cursor is empty.

Comment: @Ahmed same problem, nothing changed

Comment: A while, rather than do...while, statement removes the need for the if statement.

Comment: @Code-Guru moveToFirst() moves the cursor to the first row, will it work if you would just call while(cursor.moveToNext())? I tought cursor.moveToNext() could only be called if there is at least one row and that on the other hand could be determined with moveToFirst(). Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Code-Guru also the same problem still exists

Comment: @OmArHesham What's on line 87?

Comment: @Ahmad HashMap<String, String> details = dbo.getUserDetails();

Answer (score 0):

the column indexes in the cursor starts on a zero index much like arrays and arraylists. Here's what your table columns look like:

```
String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGIN + "("
// column index:    + title
0:    + KEY_NAME + " VARCHAR (255), " 
1:    + KEY_MAIL + " VARCHAR (255), "
2:    + KEY_PASSWORD + " VARCHAR (255), " 
3:    + KEY_ID + " VARCHAR(255), "  
4:    + "unique_id " + "VARCHAR (255), "
5:    + KEY_COURSE1 + " VARCHAR(255), " 
6:    + KEY_COURSE2 + " VARCHAR(255), " 
7:    + KEY_COURSE3 + " VARCHAR(255), "
8:    + KEY_COURSE4 + " VARCHAR(255), " 
9:    + KEY_COURSE5 + " VARCHAR(255), " 
10:    + KEY_COURSE6 + " VARCHAR(255) " +     ");";
```

As you can see, there's is no `cursor.getString(11)` as you are trying to request. this issue is easy enough to fix. but you should know that you're not limited to requesting a column by its index you can also request it by name with `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(columnName))`, where `columnName` is the String value that you assigned to the column in your create table statement. a little verbose, but it might lead less errors if the other one proves cumbersome.